# Made a website in ASP.NET 4.0, my web host is on ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I developed a website using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010.  I'm not a serious programmer, but I can get by if the software is user-friendly enough.  Anyway, I have come to learn that the website I developed was on **ASP.NET 4.0** -- I think it might be 4.0.30319, as I look in my computer-->c:/-->windows-->microsoft.net-->framework.

Anyway, the webhosting company I'm with has **ASP.NET 2.0** installed on their servers.  Consequently, when I uploaded my site, I get a runtime error, telling me that my web.config is wrong, or whatever.  But I'm positive that it's because my website is in 4.0, and their servers are on 2.0.

Well, this is a company website, so it needs to get up ASAP.  I know I could switch hosts and all that, but does anybody know of an easier fix?  I tried deleting the web.config and the site loaded, but it was all screwed up.  The site works fine in my localhost.

**So the long and short of it -- is there anything I can do to make my site work on a server that has only the ASP.NET 2.0 framework?**

Comment: The usual .NET errors will show you the server's version (if custom errors are disabled) at the bottom. Verify that it's running 2.0 before you attempt any fixes. Also, could you share the exact error message/stack trace/screenshot you're seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short; no. It would probably be faster for you to get a new host than try to backport your site to 2.0, unless it is extremely simple. But 4.0 code won't run on a 2.0 site.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Getting a new host is probably what I'll have to end up doing.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond to my question!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change hosting company, the only way is to 'downgrade' your site to .NET 2.0: 
Right click on your project -> properties -> build -> target framework

PS

this will probably involve a (big) amount of changes to your code.

Comment: Hello Mamoo.  I tried to do this.  I backed up my site, and when I opened the copy of my site up, right clicked it, properties, build, but it only offers me one option from the target framework drop down menu:  .NET framework 4.  It might come down to me switching hosts, but that's fine.  Thanks for taking the time to try to help!

Answer (score 1):

You either need to change the framework of the site or upgrade your host.

What you're asking is "how do I get an application that requires Windows 7 to run on Windows 98?"

You may be able to push the DLLs to the site (specifying they are content files and the site can then include them) but this isn't easy by any means (nor is it 100% fool-proof).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying Brad.  I think I'll just have to switch hosts if my current host won't upgrade the server I'm on to ASP.NET 4.  Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and respond!

Comment: Thank you all for being kind enough to answer me.  I switched to a new host who has ASP.NET framework on their servers, and everything is working perfectly -- for half the price!  My old host told me to reformat my website so it's ASP.NET 2.0 compatible, but thanks to you who answered me, I didn't heed his advice and I'm happy about it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonWeber: Look at that, a better solution at a more reasonable price! I consider that a win-win. Good luck and happy developing!